# Should I normalize a time record in database?

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry if this sounds dumb, I'm new in SQL coding. Btw, I'm trying to normalize a schedule and trying to do a first normal form, Should I normalize the time column ? or should I leave it like that ?

We are tasked to normalize it in all possible normal forms to eliminate redundancies and anomalies. 
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddNj5.png)

Comment: *Should I normalize* Yes, of course. *Should I normalize the time column ? or should I leave it like that ?* Show the data and how do you want to normalize it. And explain why do you want to normalize it by such way and why do you think that it must/may be  normalized at all.

Comment: @Eliseo, Welcome to SO!
Can you please share some code snippet for us to understand what you are trying to do? Also share input and expected output. Please refer to this link to learn about how to write minimum reproducible question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Eliseo, Welcome to SO!
Can you please share some code snippet for us to understand what you are trying to do? Also share input and expected output. Please refer to this link to learn about how to write minimum reproducible question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Uh there you go, just added it. I hope that can help

Answer (score 0):

When you have a column with a single time value consisting of hour, minute, second, you don't normalize it into 3 columns.

When you have, like in your case, two time values, a time range so to say, in one column, you absolutely normalize it. Create 2 columns, start_time and end_time.

When you don't do this, you can't even query the table in a normal fashion. Imagine you want to query something like `WHERE NOW() BETWEEN start_time AND end_time`. How would you do that with having the times in one column? You can't (without some very expensive extra steps).

I can't stress this enough, never ever store multiple values in one column!